# What are the differences restkit vs afnetworking vs mknetworkkit vs nsurlconnection

Tags: objective-c, web-services, nsurlconnection, restkit, afnetworking

I'm running some test on those three networking framework: ResKit, NSURLConnection and AFNetworking. And I am seeing that it is not easy to see the differences between the third party libs. What are the major differences between the those? and why? which one is best among these

Answer (score 13, accepted):

NSURLConnection is the standard Cocoa class for managing network connection.
That is the base to all these third party libs

The difference is that they are richer,They are written to improve usage of network call in the most easier way and all the basic network call is made possible by custom methods by these libraries

As a dev, Using these will give more Readability ,Performance and icing on the cake is..less code.

Restkit uses AFNetworking for the network communication ,Other than that restkit is a parser for the data coming through the network and is most suitable for RESTful webservices

MKNetworking is one of the other favorites which will have the second place in this list.Got performance and can reduce tons of code

For me,The winner is AFNetworking.It is one of the coolest framework in iOS making my programmig life much easier in network communication.Got great performance also.And uses the latest [or recent] block programming implementation which make the code super easy to read and understand

one more is there ASIHttpRequst : It was a good one but now sadly discontinued